# How do you create/add new tags on chess stackexchange?

Tags: support, tags

Do you need certain rep to do it? Is the right only reserved for mods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anyone with 150 reputation can create new tags. Also, anyone with 200 reputation can retag others' questions. (See [this privileges page](https://chess.stackexchange.com/privileges) for the full rundown.) When you apply a tag that doesn't yet exist, it is created by doing so.